# Thunderbird of Max OSX 10.4.11

Tags: macos, mac, email, thunderbird

I need to find the latest version of thunderbird that works with osx 10.4.11 but I can't find any old versions anywhere with release notes on support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, links to the older versions of Thunderbird no longer exist on the Mozilla Messaging site, no doubt because support and security patches have ceased for these versions.

You can get Thunderbird 2.0.0.24 from the official Mozilla FTP site still:

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/thunderbird/releases/2.0.0.24/mac/

This is the latest version from the 2.x series, which I believe was the last to support 10.4 Tiger.

Comment: I'm using Thunderbird 3.1.19 under Mac OS X 10.4.11 (Intel) - but I guess version 3 won't run on PPC.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a bit late to answer to this post, but I'm running Thunderbird 3.1.2 under Mac OS X 10.4.11 (PPC) and it's working.